# How to convert HEX to ASCII String?

Tags: c++, c

I have an HEX string and want it to be converted to ASCII string in C/C++. How can i accomplish this??

Not used positions are filled with #F.
Example: Digit string 1234567 shall be written in a field with 16 reserved positions (8 bytes)

```
  Byte 0 Byte 1 Byte 2 Byte 3 Byte 4 Byte 5 Byte 6 Byte 7
```

HEX   1 2    3 4    5 6    7 F    F F    F F    F F    F F

Input:
0x12 0x34 0x56 0x7f 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff

Output:
1234567

Comment: A hex string _is_ ASCII (or at least text).  What do you really have that you want to convert?

Comment: do you have C-like string `"0x12 0x34 0x56 0x7f 0xff 0xff 0xff 0xff"` ? Is count of tokens has fixed count?

Comment: parse 2 digits at a time. Put 2 digits in an char[2] and use strtoul with base=16. Then convert that to a char

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding you have shown in the example seems to be **BCD**. That is, a byte can store 2 digits. Each digit is represented by 4 bits. If the 4 bits are greater than 1001 binary (9 decimal) then you want to interpret that as a *not-valid number* , and I guess FF hex is to be interpreted as a blank space. You can use bitwise operators to access each nibble in a byte:

```
//Let's say a byte of your input is stored as 'a'
    char a = 0x15; //This is 15 BCD

    //separate lower and upper nibble
    char lower_nibble=a&0x0F;
    char upper_nibble=(a&0xF0)>>4;

    //convert to ASCII
    if(lower_nibble > 9) lower_nibble =' '; //space
    else lower_nibble = '0' + lower_nibble; //convert to ASCII
    if(upper_nibble > 9) upper_nibble =' '; //space
    else upper_nibble = '0' + upper_nibble; //convert to ASCII

    std::cout<<"\n A is: "<<upper_nibble<<" "<<lower_nibble;
```

Comment: @ Methee: In that case, you can mark the answer as 'accepted' by ticking the correct mark :)